# Slurm not running job generated by snakemake because file, directory or other parameter too long

Tags: slurm, snakemake

I have a snakemake rule that has 630k input file dependencies. This rule concatenates the files together with an R script. The R script doesn't take any input files but will grab them from within the R script. When I run this on our HPC via slurm, I'm getting the following error message...

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 4950
Job stats:
job                   count    min threads    max threads
------------------  -------  -------------  -------------
all_targets               1              1              1
simA_pool_clusters        1              1              1
total                     2              1              1

Select jobs to execute...

[Sun Feb 12 13:30:05 2023]
rule simA_pool_clusters:
    input: workflow/scripts/simA_pool_clusters.R, data/sim_a/s1_1000_1.nofilter.deseq.bray.clusters.tsv, data/sim_a/s1_1000_1.nofilter.deseq.euclidean.clusters.tsv, [snip...]
    output: data/simulation_cluster_accuracy.tsv
    jobid: 194145
    reason: Missing output files: data/simulation_cluster_accuracy.tsv
    resources: mem_mb=2000, disk_mb=1000, tmpdir=<TBD>, cores=1, partition=standard, time_min=120, job_name=rare

sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Pathname of a file, directory or other parameter too long
Error submitting jobscript (exit code 1):

Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2023-02-11T093752.352072.snakemake.log
```

Here is the snakemake rule:

```
rule simA_pool_clusters:
  input:
    R="workflow/scripts/simA_pool_clusters.R",
    tsv=expand("data/sim_a/{frac}_{depth}_{rep}.{preproc}.{transform}.{distance}.clusters.tsv",
           frac = fracs, depth = depths, rep = reps, preproc = preprocs,
           transform = transforms, distance = distances)
  conda:
    "envs/nr-modern.yml"
  output:
    "data/simulation_cluster_accuracy.tsv"
  shell:
    """
    {input.R}
    """
```

The `input.tsv` expands to 630k small files, I've shortened the list for ease of posting. The `input.R` is an executable R script with a shebang line - like I said, it gets the `*clusters.tsv` files from its own logic.

I'm wondering if it's possible that snakemake is sending the entire value of `input.tsv` to slurm rather than just the R script. Any suggestions to try before I run the R script manually outside of snakemake?

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from `simA_pool_clusters`? Maybe post more of the output log. For the sake of testing, try reducing the size of `tsv`, like `tsv=expand(...)[0:5]`, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @dariober - I added to the error message. I also reduced the size of `tsv` and it runs fine.

Comment: When/if https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/2149 is merged this issue should be solved

Answer (score 0):

> The R script doesn't take any input files but will grab them from within the R script

So you have an R script with 630k file paths hardcoded in it? If so, this [link](https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2198) says the slurm script has a limit of 4MB and you are probably over it. If so, it is a limitation of slurm rather than snakemake.

If the above is about right, you could write the 630k file paths to a text file first (one rule), and then use that file as input file to another rule.

---

Loosely related, I wonder whether the file system is going to struggle in moving around so many files. Perhaps you could consider some refactoring...

Comment: Not sure I follow - the R script is only a 1.4k file. The script grabs the files I want using the `list.files` function, pools them, and then outputs a single file. There's no movement of files.

Comment: Ok, I see my speculation was not right. Try positing a minimal working example that reproduces the problem. Another experiment I would try is to move `tsv=expand(...)` from `input` to `params` and see what happens (assuming these files already exist). Also, what is snakemake command you use?